# Does overriding dependency properties work with VCS triggers?

Tags: teamcity

Since TeamCity 9.0 it's been possible to use the `reverse.dep.<btID>.<property name>` syntax to override properties in dependencies.

I've used this syntax to have a common build which is used as a snapshot dependency by multiple other builds. i.e. Builds A, B and C all depend on D.

When I run A, B or C manually, everything works as expected. I can see the appropriate parameters are correctly overridden in D.

However, when A, B or C are triggered by a VCS Git change, D ignores the overridden values and uses its default values. ***Even though under the "Value passed to the build" column in the parameters tab, the overridden values are shown correctly.***

Is it not possible to override dependency properties when using a VCS trigger?